# How to Maintain Index of List of String After Remove Duplicate?

Tags: python, python-3.x, set, list-comprehension

I have a `list` that contains strings. Those strings aren't same. But, after I do this

```
alist = ['string1','string2'] #list of string
processed_alist = [some_function(s) for s in alist] #processing strings
```

There are some duplicate in `processed_alist` and I want to remove them. If I do

```
processed_alist = list(set(processed_alist))
```

All of strings index must be scrambled and I can't check which string from `alist` that match with string from `processed_alist`.

Is there any way to maintain string index in `processed_alist` but I can still remove duplicate string?

For example,

I have

```
alist = ['sta','tsb','sat','tsa','tsd','stb']
```

and `some_function(s)` return string with character `s` removed. So, the `processed_alist` would be

```
['ta','tb','at','ta','td','tb']
```

and after remove duplication become

```
['ta','tb','at','td']
```

I want to remove duplicate in `processed_alist` but at the same time I want the get the original string of processed string. Let say the function name is `get_original`. So, if I write

```
get_original(processed_alist[3])
#return 'tsd' because original string from 'td' is 'tsd'
get_original(processed_alist[0])
#return 'sta' or 'tsa'. I don't mind which one
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest method is using an `OrderedDict`:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> processed_alist = ['not a dupe', 'still not a dupe', 'i am dupe!', 'i am dupe!', 'err not a dupe']
>>> list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(processed_alist))
['not a dupe', 'still not a dupe', 'i am dupe!', 'err not a dupe']
```

Comment: I edited my question. I hope my question is clearer.

Comment: You essentially changed the nature of the question... I would probably have to do a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries in Python 3.6+ preserver the order. You can use `dict.fromkeys()` to retain the order while removing the duplicates:

```
result = dict().fromkeys(map(some_function, alist)).keys()
```

Note that result is a `key` object, if you necessarily want a list (not a good idea if you just want an iterable) you should do the following instead:

```
result = list(dict().fromkeys(map(some_function, alist)))
```

Also, if you're using Python-3.6- you should consider using `collections.OrderedDict()` which does the same thing with a little bit difference in performance.

Regarding the following part `map(some_function, alist)` if `some_function` is not a built-in function you'd better to use a list comprehension in case you really need your code to be as fast as possible. The reason for that is because `map` is a built-in function and works perfectly better with functions of its kind (chain rule).

Based on your update you can just use `str.replace()` instead of your function and a generator expression withing `dict.fromkeys()`:

```
In [48]: dict().fromkeys(i.replace('s', '') for i in alist).keys()
Out[48]: dict_keys(['ta', 'tb', 'at', 'td'])
```

Note that alternatively you could also use `{}` for constructing an empty dictionary which is also slightly faster than directly calling the `dict` type.

```
In [49]: %timeit dict().fromkeys(i.replace('s', '') for i in alist).keys()

1.75 µs ± 3.35 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [50]: %timeit {}.fromkeys(i.replace('s', '') for i in alist).keys()
1.67 µs ± 10.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Comment: Note: this only works for CPython for 3.6. For 3.7, all implementations should support this.